# MySQL: Is it possible to set a variable outside of SELECT with SELECT as the only permission?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.6

**WHAT**
I'm on `MySQL 5.6` and my account only has permissions for `SELECT` and `USAGE` (as found using the `SHOW GRANTS` command).

Presumably because of this using `DECLARE` before `SELECT` returns a generic syntax error.

**WHY**
I want to use variables to both make the code easier to read and maintain.
Below you can see variable `@isOwn` is needed in `WHERE` clause and the day differences could be shortened (note: `DATEDIFF` didn't work for me in `WHERE` for some reason)

**QUESTION**
Being able to declare the variables before `SELECT` would simplify everything.
Am I doing something wrong or can I not do this because of my minimal permissions?

**CODE EXAMPLE**

```
DECLARE @test INT = 5 -- <<< syntax error

SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN @isOwn := sp.`name` LIKE 'TST %'
        THEN 'O' ELSE 'S'
    END                                     AS 'Group',
    st.`name`                               AS 'Type',
    COUNT(st.`name`)                        AS 'Count',
    DATE(MIN(os.endTime))   AS 'From',
    CASE
        WHEN @isOwn
        THEN TO_DAYS(CURRENT_DATE) - TO_DAYS(MIN(os.endTime)) - 3 + 1
        ELSE TO_DAYS(CURRENT_DATE) - TO_DAYS(MIN(os.endTime)) - 28 + 1
    END                                     AS 'DO'
FROM tdb.orders                             AS os
LEFT OUTER JOIN tdb.shipment_type   AS st
    ON (st.ID = os.shipmentType_ID)
LEFT OUTER JOIN tdb.suppliers       AS sp
    ON (sp.ID = os.supplier_ID)
WHERE
    os.proof IS NULL
    AND os.endTime IS NOT NULL
    AND ((
        sp.`name` NOT LIKE 'TST %' AND 
        (TO_DAYS(CURRENT_DATE) - TO_DAYS(os.endTime)) >= 3
    ) OR (
        sp.`name` NOT LIKE 'TST %' AND
        (TO_DAYS(CURRENT_DATE) - TO_DAYS(os.endTime)) >= 28
    ))
    AND YEAR(os.endTime) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
 GROUP BY
    CASE
        WHEN sp.`name` LIKE 'TST %'
        THEN 'O' ELSE 'S'
    END,
    st.`name`
```

Comment: Are you sure you need `DECLARE` keyword? It will work without it, like `SET @test INT = 5;` You only need to declare variables _without_ `@`.

Comment: @gaborsch I should've mentioned this, but I tried `DECLARE`, `SET` and even plain variable with value, but all return syntax error on that line I'm afraid.

Comment: You also miss a semicolon at the end, that may also cause a syntax error.

Comment: @gaborsch please add this to your answer so I can mark it, that was the reason - many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SET` keyword instead of `DECLARE`. The latter is only needed in stored procedures and functions, to define *local variables*.

You need an *user variable*, which is different, for example it is not required to define it and it has no strict type. User variables have `@` prefix, local variables don't. But you can still access it, even from stored procedures/functions.

Also, as commented, you need to separate the two statements (`SET` and `SELECT`) with a delimiter `;` (or perhaps call them as two statements on the same connection).

Comment: sorry this doesn't work (syntax error), but I did notice that with `SET @test INT = 5`, I get syntax error on the same line, but with `SET @test = 5`, the syntax error says line with `SELECT` on it, right below the `SET` line. The code without `SET` works fine though. Not sure if this helps finding the issue...

Comment: You will need two statements on the same connection, One for `SET @test = 5;`, and the other for the `SELECT`. Not sure how you call it, but it may be the cause, too.
If you are running a script, then please check the delimiter (semicolon) to separate the statements - that may cause the error on `SELECT` statement.